# Having Problems Running my Testng Test Suite on Jenkins

Tags: maven, selenium, jenkins, testng, surefire

Here is the stacktrace error that I am seeing

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.8.1:test (default-test) @ eselenium-smartpearsonplayer-pageobjects ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: c:\jenkins\workspace\MediaPlayerTest\target\surefire-reports
There are no tests to run.
```

I know that this could be due to anything. So let me try to give you more information and although it's a long shot, maybe you can help.
I am using selenium webdriver 2.29 to write tests.
I am also building with maven.
I am trying to use testng to configure which tests I'm using.
I am using jenkins to run the maven project and I am trying to do "clean verify" and sometimes "clean test" because I don't know the difference between the two.

Locally I am using eclipse. Locally I can run the tests on maven using maven test, and using maven verify.

Here is something in my pom.

```
<!-- attempt to use surefire to run tests -->
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                             <suiteXmlFile>src\test\resources\testng\TestBrowserPOC_Test.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end attempt -->
```

Again, the tests run fine when I do a maven verify on eclipse.

Here is my testng xml.

```
<!DOCTYPE Suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite name="BrowserPOC_Tests">

        <!-- class does not exist -->
        <!-- <test name="Demo Test"> <parameter name="url"     value="src/test/resources/testData/login.html"></parameter> 
            <groups> <run> <exclude name="errorDetector"></exclude> </run> </groups> 
            <classes> <class name="com.pearson.demotests.DemoTestIT" /> </classes>         </test> -->
        <test name="POC test">
            <groups>
                <run>
                    <include name="volumeTest"></include>
                </run>
            </groups>
            <classes>
                <class name="com.pearson.poc_tests.BrowserPOCIT" />
            </classes>
        </test>
</suite>
```

Right now I am going to try changing the name of my xml to follow a "naming convention" and see if that does anything. Again the tests run fine on eclipse, just not on jenkins. I'm not sure what to do from here or what other information I need. My steps from here are just to get more help from a jenkins expert.

Oh and I think my naming convention for the test xml is correct.
I also think I am using a freestyle project that builds as maven.
Should I be using "mvn clean test" instead of "clean test"?

Comment: Have you tried to run `mvn test` without Eclipse, i.e. from a command line?

Comment: is ur testcode available in the workspace?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone. It turns out I had two repositories in my jenkins configuration. Jenkins was looking for tests in the wrong project.

Answer (score 0):

I used maven fail-safe plugin in the past. Below was my configuration. You would run `mvn clean verify` . `mvn clean` is always recommended because it will delete your target directory before compiling and running the tests.

```
<properties>
        <functionalSourceDirectory>src/itest</functionalSourceDirectory>
</properties>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
    <configuration>
       <testSourceDirectory>${functionalSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
       <suiteXmlFiles>
         <suiteXmlFile>src/itest/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
       </suiteXmlFiles>
     </configuration>
     <executions>
        <execution>
           <id>verify</id>
           <phase>verify</phase>
           <goals>
             <goal>verify</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
```